# git gpg sign everything

Tags: git, gnupg, pgp

I am trying to sign every operation I do via git.

**sign commit**

```
git commit -S -am 'message'
```

**sign tag**

```
git tag -s -a <tag>
```

**sign merge**

```
git merge -S <branch>
```

However one problem remains. When I simply pull, it sometimes automatically creates a merge with the pull which is not signed.

So how can I sign a merge that is done by `git pull`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that will be good enough for you, but you can pull without the merge commit, and perform the commit manually

```
git pull --no-commit
git commit -S -am 'The merge commit'
```

Comment: As this seems to be the only method to achieve the above, I will accept it as the correct answer. Thanks!